# How do i store jsonwebtoken on cookie for front-end so client can send back the token for auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I've been struggling to do this for about 6 days...
Everything is working perfectly such as authorization but one problem I had is making authentication.

On my user model (for creating the database schema) I do have a way to generate a token for logged in users or registered.

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    return token;
}
```

So when user post to /login, server will respond with a token:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) =>{
    // Here i'm validating data and then if everything is right the code under will run.
    console.log('logged in as: ' + user.username);
    // Here i'm using the function to generateAuthToken().
    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    console.log("Token from server: " + token);
    // now here is my main problem i would like to use cookies to store it for an hour or so.
    // then client can send it back to server for protected route.
    res.status(200).send(token);
});
```

I have made a middleware function for auth (to check the token if you're going through a protected route)

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next){
    // instead of using headers i would like to check for the cookie value if it's the token,
    // pass the user in, else Access denied.
    // I have no idea how to use cookie parser with middleware functions.
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send('Access denied. Sign in or register.');

    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send('Invalid Token!');
    }
}
```

here i'm using the auth middleware function:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

// but it's actually not passing the user in since i haven't done it with cookies.
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index', {});
});
```

I do know I can do it with localStorage but it's a terrible practice and it would be better to store it on cookies so no one could hack on.
Is there any good approach to solve this problem? I'm kinda lost and lost hope to go back to sessionID (which I don't want to :( ).

Answer (score 0):

After you request on frontend, you need get the **response** (token) and **save** on **browser** using this for example:

```
fetch('http://your-api-host/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      username: "user1",
      password: "passworduser" 
    }
 })
.then((res) => res.text((res)))
.then((token) => {
   document.cookie = `AUTH_API=${token}`;  <-- this save the cookie
})
```

With this value saved on frontend you need send this information on all requests, it's commum send this value on your HEADER (how you makes), to save on header you need read the value from token and put on header, like this:

```
const headersTemp = document.cookie.split(';');   // <-- this get all cookies saves and splits them in the array.

const finalHeaders = {};
headersTemp.forEach((header) => {   // <-- looping on all cookies
  const headerTemp = header.split('='); // <-- split each cookie to get key and value
  finalHeaders[headerTemp[0].trim()] = headerTemp[1].trim()   // <-- save on object to access using keys.
})
```

Now you can access all cookies using the key (the same used before), I used the key **AUTH_API** to save my cookie, let's send the request using fetch api:

```
fetch('http://your-api-host/route-protected', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'x-auth-token': finalHeaders['AUTH_API']
    },
  })
```

If you creating your application using libraries how React or any SPA framework, probably you will use tools like Axios, and I recommend uses libraris how [This](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie/#readme), it's more easy to work with cookies.